# Pandas Mask query

Tags: python, pandas

I have a query in masks - My X is defined as below

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,250,480],
               'b':[60,51,101],
               'c':[15,689,1],
               'd':[1,1,1],
               'e':[2,2,2]})
```

which gives my X as below

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   60  15  1   2
1   250 51  689 1   2
2   480 101 1   1   2
```

When I create a mask as
 `x['d'] =x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b")`

I get the below output..

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   60  15  1   2
1   250 51  689 b   2
2   480 101 1   480 2
```

I don't understand where the 480 in column d is coming from.

Specifically x['d'] is now [1 b 480]
The b is clear, but where is 480 coming from ?? I think i am missing something about how masks work

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is by design if assign `DataFrame` to one column it assign first column of `DataFrame`.

---

It use first column like if not specified columns - here is used [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), because `x` is passed to `mask` (not specified column name after `x`):

```
#replaced to `b` value all columns in df by mask x['c'] >100       
print (x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b"))
      ^^^ 
     a    b   c  d  e
0    1   60  15  1  2
1    b    b   b  b  b
2  480  101   1  1  2
```

And if assign to some column is used first column:

```
x['d'] = x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b")
        ^^^ 
print (x)
     a    b    c    d  e
0    1   60   15    1  2
1  250   51  689    b  2
2  480  101    1  480  2
```

Test with removed first column `a`, then is assigned first column,  here `b`:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({ 'b':[60,51,101],
               'c':[15,689,1],
               'd':[1,1,1],
               'e':[2,2,2]})

print (x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b"))
      ^^^ 
     b   c  d  e
0   60  15  1  2
1    b   b  b  b
2  101   1  1  2

x['d'] = x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b")
        ^^^ 
print (x)
     b    c    d  e
0   60   15   60  2
1   51  689    b  2
2  101    1  101  2
```

---

If assign DataFrame to column without condition, same behaviour:

```
x['d'] = x
        ^^^ 
print (x)
     a    b    c    d  e
0    1   60   15    1  2
1  250   51  689  250  2
2  480  101    1  480  2
```

---

If want assign to 2 columns it correctly raise error:

```
x[['d','e']] = x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b")
              ^^^ 
print (x)
```

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Correct way with specified column with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) - `Series`, (column) are assigned, because specified column name after `x` is passed `Series`, here `x['d']`, `x['b']`:

```
#replaced to `b` value only column `d` in df by mask x['c'] >100  
print (x['d'].mask(x['c'] >100, "b"))
        ^^^ 
0    1
1    b
2    1
Name: d, dtype: object

#replaced to `b` value only column `b` in df by mask x['c'] >100  
print (x['b'].mask(x['c'] >100, "b"))
         ^^^ 
0     60
1      b
2    101
Name: b, dtype: object


x['d'] = x['d'].mask(x['c'] >100, "b")
           ^^^ 
x['e'] = x['b'].mask(x['c'] >100, "b")
           ^^^ 
print (x)
     a    b    c  d    e
0    1   60   15  1   60
1  250   51  689  b    b
2  480  101    1  1  101
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what the difference between  Case1: x['d'] = x['d'].mask(x['c'] >100, "b")  AND Case2: x['d'] = x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b") is ?

Comment: @HopeKing - I add `^^^` for see difference

Comment: Sorry, i meant the interpretation. Is it that in Case 1 ['d'] = x['d'].mask(x['c'] >100, "b")  we create a mask and then apply only in x['d']. While in Case 2 x['d'] = x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b") we didnt apply the mask on anything and hence pandas took the first column by default. Would that be correct interpretation.

Comment: @HopeKing - I understand. `we didnt apply the mask on anything` - No, there is aplies mask for all columns, so replacement, see `print (x.mask(x['c'] >100, "b"))` and then is assigned first column of output to `d` column

Comment: ok. So in Case 2 we applied the mask only on x['d']. I guess both could have their use cases. Regarding your first line stating that it is a bug - I have a feeling it could be by "design"....if you assign a dataframe to a column, take the first column of the dataframe since you have not specified.

Comment: @HopeKing - hmmm, I think you are right, because if use `x['d'] = x` working same.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me  understand some code which used Case2 heavily and  indirectly the first column values were coming up and I couldn't  understand how for the last many hours.